# IE7 jquery text update issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am having a shopping cart text update issue on an ASP.NET MVC2 ecommerce site. When a user wants to add an item, a user control pop-up allows them to choose certain options and then click on "add to cart".

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sizeselectform :radio:first').attr('checked', 'checked');

        $('#sizeselectform').ajaxForm(function () {
            $('#sizeselectform').parents('div.popup').children('a.close').click();
            UpdateCartCount();
        });

    });
```

The UpdateCartCount function just updates the count of items in a shopping cart:

```
function UpdateCartCount() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ShoppingCart/GetCartItemsCount/",
        success: function (result, status, xmlHttpRequest) {            
            $('#cartItemCount').text(result);
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, status, e) {
            var errorMessage = 'Login: ' + xmlHttpRequest.status + ' - ' + xmlHttpRequest.statusText;
            $('#loginErrorMessage').html(errorMessage).show();
        },
        complete: function (xmlHttpRequest, status) {

        }
    });    
}
```

Everything works fine in Chrome, Firefox,etc except IE7. I suspect that the cart count is not updated in IE7 because the parent div is closed before called the UpdateCartCount() function but at this point I am not sure. Any suggestions?

Thanks,

**EDIT:**

I changed the call to POST, added a cache: 'false', content-type: 'application/text', and finally a random number to the URL to prevent caching (all suggested solutions to this IE issue)...and the ajax calls finally started working in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the call to POST, added a cache: 'false', content-type: 'application/text', and finally a random number to the URL to prevent caching (all suggested solutions to this IE issue)...and the ajax calls finally started working in IE.

Answer (score 0):

If the div#cartItemCount won't be removed in this process, there shouldn't be any problems
Did you check if the ajax call is triggered in IE7?
You could use IE8 in IE7 mode for easier debugging or put some alerts() in the code to check if UpdateCartCount() with $ajax gets really called

Comment: Thanks phikin - I inserted an alert(results) statement in the ajax success callback. It runs in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE. So it looks like the ajax call is not being triggered in IE. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check the value of `result` in your success callback. Maybe you have to specify the `dataType: 'text'` for your ajax request. I assume it is text, not HTML or Json.